# Django on Windows with DB2 fails

Tags: django, db2

I am using:

- Windows 10 Pro

  IBM DB2 V11.1

  Python 3.7

  Django 2.1.4

  ibm_db 2.0.9

  ibm_db_django 1.1.1.2

After setting the connection information in settings.py and running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the errors (tail only):

> File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py",
>   line 203, in contribute_to_class
>       self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
>
> File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 33,
>   in **getattr**
>       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
>
> File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 203,
>   in **getitem**
>       conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
>
> File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_django\base.py", line
>   155, in **init**
>       super( DatabaseWrapper, self ).**init**( *args )
>
> File
>   "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line
>   101, in **init**
>       self.client = self.client_class(self)
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

The same setup works fine on MacOS. A simple python program using ibm_db works fine on Windows.

Comment: Please EDIT your question to add the full result of following the IBM documentation for testing the ibm_db_django adapter at item 4 on this page: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0060891.html .  You may need USE_TZ = false in your settings.py first, for your project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the correct version of ibm_db_django was not installed.

pip install ibm_db_django installed version 1.1.1.2 but it is necessary to install version 1.2.0.0 for Python V3 and current Django.

Strangely, pip install ibm_db_django==1.2.0.0 fails but it is possible to issue pip install ibm_db_django==1.2.0.0a0 which resolves the problem.

The IBM install directions at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0060891.html don't refer to this information. The IBM directions also specify that INSTALLED_APPS need to include flatpages, comments and redirects but including these causes a failure.

The documentation at https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django appears outdated (Ubuntu 7.04?)

Comment: I followed the IBM instructions to use easy_install (not pip) for the ibm_db and ibm_db_django components, and those versions allowed the python 3.7.2 to work, and start the server, although I had to ignore IBM's outdated documentation for outdated contrib modules, and add USE_TZ = false.  But the server did start successfully without needing to use pip directly for the IBM components.